# Error publishing on Agora Web SDK v4 with Electron

Tags: electron, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I followed the steps as mentioned in the docs. I have an Electron application with React. I was earlier using agora v3.6.0 and everything was working fine. I want to upgrade to Agora v4 which isn't backward compatible, but looked easy enough to implement.

I am receiving the following error after I publish my local tracks.

```
AgoraRTC_N-production.js:637 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.report.forEach is not a function
    at b.<anonymous> (AgoraRTC_N-production.js:637)
    at AgoraRTC_N-production.js:175
    at Object.next (AgoraRTC_N-production.js:176)
    at g (AgoraRTC_N-production.js:174)
```

Code snippet from my project:

```
const agoraAccessToken = await actions.auth.getAgoraAccessToken({ requestParams: {channel: props.config.channel}});
console.log(agoraAccessToken);


let uid = await AgoraClient.join(props.config.appId, props.config.channel, agoraAccessToken);
console.log(uid);

let audioTrack = await AgoraRTC.createMicrophoneAudioTrack();
let videoTrack = await AgoraRTC.createCameraVideoTrack();

await AgoraClient.publish([audioTrack, videoTrack]);
```

Comment: Could you edit the question with some code?

Comment: Hi @AkshatGupta Added the snippet, similar as the other question I had.

Answer (score 0):

As you are aware the Agora 4.x SDK is not backwards compatible.

The differences are not limited to only the initialization of `tracks`. Another area where the 3.x and 4.x differs is with regard to `in-call stats`, which could be causing the `this.report.forEach` error, but this is only an assumption until you provide more code.

If you are using react I would suggest you check out the open-source [Agora React](https://github.com/AgoraIO-Community/agora-rtc-react/tree/master/example) project, it wraps the Agora 4.x SDK to follow the standard React code style.

[Full Guide: Building a Video Chat App Using React Hooks and Agora](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/building-a-video-chat-app-using-react-hooks-and-agora/)

> Note: I did not personally create this project nor did I write this guide, but I am recommending them because they were created for the purpose of making it easier to use Agora's Web SDKs with React.

Comment: Ummm, the error is thrown at AgoraRTC_N-production.js:637 which is the Agora V4 SDK library itself.

Comment: Is there anywhere else you are calling the Agora engine? please provide more context as to when this error is being thrown. Is it happening when you join the channel? or some other time? The 4.x SDK has changed a lot more than just the initialization of tracks instead of streams.

Comment: Yes, it's as it says in the question. The error appears as soon as publish method is called. And this is the only piece of code I have related to Agora as of now, since it's failing at the bare minimum, hence I haven't written anything else.

Comment: Have you created a new client using the `createClient` method before join and publish?
https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/API%20Reference/web_ng/interfaces/iagorartc.html#createclient